# Appending data from another row to an above or below row entry in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, arcgis, dataformat

I am a research biologist who is relatively new at coding. I am working on cleaning up a dataset and automating a process to then be used in ArcGIS. I have a dataset from 2015 of about 10 birds that I am using as a sample year for right now. The end result I am looking for is a csv file for each bird, with a one to one join for each 15 minute GPS point to the spatial location I have. Where I run into issues is that the data loggers also have a dive logger for when the bird dives, but there is not specific GPS coordinates for dives.

Now I am a bit stuck. I need to combine the dive duration entries to the lat and long to the most taken GPS point to create a 1:1 join in ArcGIS (either the point above or below depending on timing). I would love to be able to create a code that results in the following (with potentially another column that has information for number of dives):

BIRD 1 TIME DATE LATITUDE LONGITUDE    DIVE DURATION  NUMBER OF DIVES

Is there a feature in `dplyr` that can help with this?

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: My current code:

```
# Start by connecting to 2015 data
data2015 <- read.csv("GPS data 2015\\GPS2015Birds.csv")

# select out individual logger.ID
i <- "GRE12"

# Now this starts to filter only the information wanted in the final CSV file

birdo <- data2015 %>%
  filter(LoggerID== i)

birdie <- birdo %>%
  filter(!is.na(Latitude)|Divingduration %in% c(4:120))
```

This is a sample of some of the data:

```
head(birdie)

   LoggerID Year Month Day Hour Minute Second Latitude Longitude Divingduration
1     GRE12 2015     6  19   23     38      0 51.03007 -39.78358             NA
2     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     18      0 55.02958 -39.79267             NA
3     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     19      0 45.02962 -39.79262             NA
4     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     19      0 65.02960 -39.79275             NA
5     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     23      0 62.02960 -39.79272             NA
6     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     24      0 23.02960 -39.79257             NA
7     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     24      0 34.02955 -39.79247             NA
8     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     31      0 76.02958 -39.79275             NA
9     GRE12 2015     6  21   12     31      0 61.02960 -39.79267             NA
10    GRE12 2015     6  21   12     32      0 67.02958 -39.79270             NA
11    GRE12 2015     6  21   12     32      0 54.02960 -39.79277             NA
12    GRE12 2015     6  21   12     33      0 98.02963 -39.79272             NA
13    GRE12 2015     6  21   12     37     16       NA        NA             24
14    GRE12 2015     6  21   12     48      0 12.03137 -39.79330             NA
15    GRE12 2015     6  21   13      3      0 41.03152 -39.79270             NA
16    GRE12 2015     6  21   13     18      0 98.03187 -39.79252             NA
17    GRE12 2015     6  21   13     33      0 43.03185 -39.79258             NA
18    GRE12 2015     6  21   13     49      0 59.03187 -39.79262             NA
19    GRE12 2015     6  21   14      4      0 38.03245 -39.79222             NA
20    GRE12 2015     6  21   14     19      0 93.03245 -39.79250             NA
21    GRE12 2015     6  21   14     35      0 69.03245 -39.79237             NA
22    GRE12 2015     6  21   14     50      0 32.04337 -39.80202             NA
23    GRE12 2015     6  21   15      5      0 54.05958 -39.88438             NA
24    GRE12 2015     6  21   15     20      0 76.05950 -39.88617             NA
25    GRE12 2015     6  21   15     35      0 23.05945 -39.88620             NA
26    GRE12 2015     6  21   15     51      0 43.05943 -39.88617             NA
27    GRE12 2015     6  21   16      3     16       NA        NA              4
28    GRE12 2015     6  21   16      6      0 99.05950 -39.88662             NA
29    GRE12 2015     6  21   16     21      0 63.05517 -39.89503             NA
30    GRE12 2015     6  21   16     33     46       NA        NA              4
31    GRE12 2015     6  21   16     34     48       NA        NA              6
32    GRE12 2015     6  21   16     37      0 78.04935 -39.90928             NA
33    GRE12 2015     6  21   16     37     42       NA        NA              7
```

Comment: Hi reeto9, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(data[1:20,])`. Replace `data` with the name of your data object. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the pasted output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks for the suggestions, I've reformatted to hopefully provide clarity!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with the `fuzzyjoin` package:

First, let's combine the various time components into one datetime column:

```
library(lurbidate)
library(dplyr)
birdie <- birdie %>%
  mutate(Time = mdy_hms(paste(Month,Day,Year,Hour, Minute, Second))) %>%
  select(LoggerID, Latitude, Longitude, Divingduration, Time)
```

Now, we will separate the birdie data into to sets, rows with Lat/Long data, and those rows with `Divingduration` data.

Then we can use a `difference_join`, to join on the times within a certain distance, in the clase, I used 15 minutes (`60*15`).

After the join is complete, we can group by `LoggerID.x` and make sure the `LoggerID`s are the same, and then filter for rows where the time difference is minimum.

Lastly, we can select the columns we're interested in.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
birdie %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Latitude)) %>%
  difference_inner_join(birdie %>% filter(!is.na(Divingduration)),
                        by = "Time", max_dist = 60*15) %>%
  group_by(LoggerID.x,Time.y) %>%
  filter(LoggerID.x == LoggerID.y &
           abs(Time.x - Time.y) == min(abs(Time.x - Time.y))) %>%
  select(LoggerID.x,Latitude.x,Longitude.x, Time.x, Divingduration.y,Time.y)

# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   LoggerID.x, Time.y [5]
  LoggerID.x Latitude.x Longitude.x Time.x              Divingduration.y Time.y             
  <fct>           <dbl>       <dbl> <dttm>                         <int> <dttm>             
1 GRE12            98.0       -39.8 2015-06-21 12:33:00               24 2015-06-21 12:37:16
2 GRE12            99.1       -39.9 2015-06-21 16:06:00                4 2015-06-21 16:03:16
3 GRE12            78.0       -39.9 2015-06-21 16:37:00                4 2015-06-21 16:33:46
4 GRE12            78.0       -39.9 2015-06-21 16:37:00                6 2015-06-21 16:34:48
5 GRE12            78.0       -39.9 2015-06-21 16:37:00                7 2015-06-21 16:37:42
```